# Is there any way to add pkg_check_modules dependency on ExternalProject_Add target

Tags: cmake

I am importing a third-party library (dpdk) from tar using ExternalProject_Add

```
ExternalProject_Add( build-dpdk
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dpdk-20.11.1.tar.xz
    URL_MD5 c6be9347f0200dc5315035720b732499

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND meson <BINARY_DIR> <SOURCE_DIR> 
    BUILD_COMMAND ninja
    INSTALL_COMMAND DESTDIR=<INSTALL_DIR> ninja install
)
```

It installs the libraries and libdpdk.pc at the install location at build stage. Next I need to use cmake pkg-config module to check libdpdk package and set result variables

```
pkg_check_modules(DPDK REQUIRED libdpdk)
```

But pkg_check_modules is triggered at configure stage. Is there any way to add dependency of pkg_check_modules on ExternalProject_Add?

Comment: Can you please post the current result for `pkg-config --cflags --libs libdpdk`? As far I recollect the default `pkg_check_modules(DPDK REQUIRED libdpdk)` checks in standard folders like `/usr/lib/ /usr/include/` to lookup for libraries and headers. Since you are using `ExternalProject_Add` as a separate function to build and install, did you try adding `ldconfig` at end of `INSTALL_COMMAND DESTDIR=<INSTALL_DIR> ninja install`.

Comment: are there any update on checking the parameters as suggested in comemnt?

Comment: Yes, pkg_check_modules will check in the standard folders as you mentioned. In order to provide a specific search path either we can set env variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH or set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. The issue is that I did find a way to call pkg_check_modules only after ExternalProject_Add builds and installs libdpdk.pc. The former is triggered in configure stage while the latter in build stage.

Comment: so did ldconfig after install work for you?